# How to find number port of IP camera?

Tags: c++, ip-camera

I've known MAC address of a IP camera. So, how to find number port of the IP camera using C++?

Comment: There's nothing I can say to this. Other than this.

Comment: @Alex: He asked for the service's TCP/IP port. It's probably written in the user manual.

Comment: Some IP cameras provide information for accessing them via DNS Service Discovery (dns-sd). That makes it easy for your program to get a list of all the available cameras, present a list of human readable camera names to your user, connect to them by name, and persist the user's choice across network changes (e.g., the camera's IP address changes, or the camera itself is swapped out as long as the new camera uses the same service instance name).

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short uiClientPort = socket().remote_endpoint().port();
```

Hope this helps you...